# Bootstrap <li> element not creating new line

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am creating a sidebar menu. The code is shown here:

```
<div class="row m-t-1 p-l-1">
  <h5 class="font-bold">{{brandsTitle}}</h5>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked f-1pt2" *ngFor="let menu of brandsMenu">
    <li class="m-b-pt5">{{menu.type}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row m-t-1 p-l-1">
  <h5 class="font-bold">{{washersTitle}}</h5>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked f-1pt2 line-ht-1pt5" *ngFor="let menu 
    of washersMenu"> 
    <li class="m-b-pt5">{{menu.type}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The first segment of code creates the brand menu but the items are created on the same line instead of appearing on a new line as shown here. Some items have no space between them.

```
Appliance Brands
AmanaWhirlpool
FrigidaireGEMaytag
Samsung
```

I expect:

```
Appliance Brands
Amana
Whirlpool
Frigidaire
GE
Maytag
Samsung
```

The second segment of code produces the washer menu as expected.

```
Washers
Top Load Washers
Front Load Washers
Unitized Washers & Dryers
```

Comment: Did you try Brandon's suggestion with `flex-column`? That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each menu in it's own `li`, the `*ngFor` needs to appear on that element, not the `ul`.

```
<div class="row m-t-1 p-l-1">
  <h5 class="font-bold">{{ brandsTitle }}</h5>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked f-1pt2">
    <li class="m-b-pt5" *ngFor="let menu of brandsMenu">{{ menu.type }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row m-t-1 p-l-1">
  <h5 class="font-bold">{{ washersTitle }}</h5>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked f-1pt2 line-ht-1pt5"> 
    <li class="m-b-pt5" *ngFor="let menu of washersMenu">{{ menu.type }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor for more information.

Additionally, if you want a vertical nav in Bootstrap, you need:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menu of washersMenu">
    <a class="nav-link">{{ menu.type }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#vertical

Comment: What does your `brandsMenu` and `washersMenu` data look like?

Comment: Also, what does the output of your code look like? If the structure of the HTML is correct, and each value is in it's own `<li>` element, it's a CSS issue.

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ad7378cf36d28165c059b8e"
    },
    "id": "Appliances",
    "kind": "Appliance Brands",
    "type": "Amana"
}

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ad738a9f36d28165c059d50"
    },
    "id": "Appliances",
    "kind": "Washers",
    "type": "Top Load Washers"
}

Comment: and you have an array of those objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169270/discussion-between-brandon-and-koque).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brandon, unless you want to create a bunch of ul elements place the ngFor on the li element.

However that's not your problem...

Because even then multiple ul elements should line break.  The issue is your ul class="nav-pills".  Bootstrap places the li items inline.  So either remove the class or override it with dipslay:block so that each ul (or li) line breaks.

Comment: I removed the nav-pills and used display:block. Still didn't work.

Comment: Remove the "nav" class.  If you need some of the styling for that element, I suggest overriding it.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/ should give you a better idea of some of the flexing you can do.